# on_server_join doesn't respond. discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get an output when the bot is invited to a server, but for some reason when I try to test my code it doesn't output anything. It doesn't give any errors as well. First I tried to do it from a Cog file:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_server_join(self,server):
        print("hello")
        print(server.id)
```

then in the main file:

```
@client.event
async def on_server_join(server):
    print("hello world")
    print(server.id)
```

both doesn't result in any errors and they doesn't output anything when I'm kicking the bot from a server and then adding him back.
Other events, like `on_ready` and `on_member_join` are working OK.

Creating a new server and adding the bot there also doesn't trigger the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_server_join` was [changed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=on_server_join) to [`on_guild_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_join) when discord.py migrated to v1.0